# Non-free MalwareBytes & SpybotS&D vs. Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: ms-security-essentials, malwarebytes, spybot-sd

After years of benefiting from the free versions of MalwareBytes and SpyBot S&D, it's time I contributed a paltry sum to them by buying their home versions (and it is home where I use them). However, they come with extra protection, whereas I only used the free versions for on-demand scans of selected files. Am I at risk of creating conflicts with Microsoft Security Essentials and the native Windows 7 firewall by upgrading to paid versions of MalwareBytes and Spybot S&D?

I posted this to [wilderssecurity.com](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/non-free-malwarebytes-spybots-d-vs-microsoft-security-essentials.411659) yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these products do not conflict with the Windows firewall or with Defender,
and have been crafted to work alongside the Windows products.

My only worry with having three run-time protections active at the same time,
would be the triple chances for false positives.

If you would need to exempt some folder from these protections,
as is the case with some too-clever utilities such as
[Windows Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/),
you would need to do it three times.

If one of these utilities will quarantine a product you need, you would need
to check three products to return it from quarantine.

I would therefore advise not to activate run-time protection in all three products at the same time, leaving at least Defender running (as it is the best integrated
into Windows).

Comment: I hope that last sentence was a typo, and meant two of the three? ;) Otherwise you are telling him to disable the protection he currently has running.

Comment: @LPChip: Mathematically speaking, "not all" doesn't conflict with "some". I improved the sentence so it cannot be understood as "none".

Comment: Thanks, harrymc.  I will leave MSE real-time activated, and avoid
real-time features of MalwareBytes and Spybot S&D.  I suspected that this
would be the answer, but just doing due diligence after hearing reservations from
microsoft support about multiple antiviruses. I installed the free 3rd party AVs
last night, and with your answer above, I'll find an opportunity to buy
home versions and explore their added functionality, outside of real-time.

Comment: @user2153235 MSE and Malwarebytes is absolutely compatible with one another.  As for Spybot, a long discontinued use of that useless program, since it only static signature detection.

Comment: I only use 3rd party AVs for on-demand scan of selected files, and I update the definitions just before doing so.  Spybot S&D also has immunization.